# How to use a NSNumberFormatter with an AttributedString?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nsattributedstring, nstextfield, nsnumberformatter

I have been unable to find anything that works on the subject of using an attributed text in a `NSTextField` with a `NumberFormatter`. What I want to accomplish is very simple. I would like to use a `NumberFormatter` on an editable `NSTextField` with attributed text and keep the text attributed.

Currently, I have subclassed `NSTextFieldCell` and implemented it as so:

```
class AdjustTextFieldCell: NSTextFieldCell {

  required init(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    let attributes = makeAttributes()
    allowsEditingTextAttributes = true
    attributedStringValue = AttributedString(string: stringValue, attributes: attributes)
    //formatter = TwoDigitFormatter()
  }

  func makeAttributes() -> [String: AnyObject] {
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.minimumLineHeight = 100
    style.maximumLineHeight = 100
    style.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0
    style.paragraphSpacing = 0
    style.alignment = .center
    style.lineHeightMultiple = 1.0
    style.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    let droidSansMono = NSFont(name: "DroidSansMono", size: 70)!
    return [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style, NSFontAttributeName: droidSansMono, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: -60]
  }


}
```

This implementation adjusts the text in the `NSTextField` instance to have the shown attributes. When I uncomment the line that sets the `formatter` property the `NSTextField` loses its attributes. My `NumberFormatter` is as follows:

```
class TwoDigitFormatter: NumberFormatter {

  override init() {
    super.init()
    let customAttribs = makeAttributes()
    textAttributesForNegativeValues = customAttribs.attribs
    textAttributesForPositiveValues = customAttribs.attribs
    textAttributesForZero = customAttribs.attribs
    textAttributesForNil = customAttribs.attribs
  }

  required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
  }

  let maxLength = 2
  let wrongCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted

  override func isPartialStringValid(_ partialString: String, newEditingString newString: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?, errorDescription error: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<NSString?>?) -> Bool {
    if partialString.characters.count > maxLength {
      return false
    }

    if partialString.rangeOfCharacter(from: wrongCharacterSet) != nil {
      return false
    }

    return true
  }

  override func attributedString(for obj: AnyObject, withDefaultAttributes attrs: [String : AnyObject]? = [:]) -> AttributedString? {
    let stringVal = string(for: obj)

    guard let string = stringVal else { return nil }
    let customAttribs = makeAttributes()
    var attributes = attrs
    attributes?[NSFontAttributeName] = customAttribs.font
    attributes?[NSParagraphStyleAttributeName] = customAttribs.style
    attributes?[NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName] = customAttribs.baselineOffset

    return AttributedString(string: string, attributes: attributes)

  }

  func makeAttributes() -> (font: NSFont, style: NSMutableParagraphStyle, baselineOffset: CGFloat, attribs: [String: AnyObject]) {
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.minimumLineHeight = 100
    style.maximumLineHeight = 100
    style.paragraphSpacingBefore = 0
    style.paragraphSpacing = 0
    style.alignment = .center
    style.lineHeightMultiple = 1.0
    style.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
    let droidSansMono = NSFont(name: "DroidSansMono", size: 70)!
    return (droidSansMono, style, -60, [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style, NSFontAttributeName: droidSansMono, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName: -60])
  }
}
```

As you can see from the code directly above I have tried:

1. Setting the `textAttributesFor...` properties.
2. Overriding `attributedString(for obj: AnyObject, withDefaultAttributes attrs: [String : AnyObject]? = [:])`

I have tried both these solution separately from each other and together, of which none of the attempts worked.

**TLDR**: 
Is it possible to use attributed text and a `NumberFormatter` at the same time? If so, how? If not, how can I limit a `NSTextField` with attributed text to digits only and two characters without using a `NumberFormatter`?

Comment: What didn't work for you? I tried this (actually simplified it a bit: https://gist.github.com/robertmryan/998a452a9a83eb4dbec4bebd2da52337) and it seemed to work fine. I'm trying to understand what behavior you experienced and how it differed from what you expected?

Comment: @CodeDifferent I am using Swift 3.

Comment: @Rob The behavior I am expecting is that the text in the `NSTextField` will be formatted according to the `NumberFormatter` but retain its attributes. It differs from what I expect because the text in the `NSTextField` is formatted but loses it attributes (i.e. font, paragraph style, etc). The code you posted does not seem to work for me. Beyond hooking up the `@IBOutlet` is there anything else you did in the Main.storyboard file?

Comment: When editing, the attributed styles are not present, but when you leave the text field and go to another text field, the attributed text styles reappear. If you go back and edit, the formatting disappears again until you're done editing. Is that the behavior you're seeing?

Comment: @Rob on closer inspection the formatting is kept in your code, but not while  the `NSTextField` is being edited. Is there anyway to keep the attributes **during** editing of the `NSTextField`?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I looked around and have seen several references to this behavior, but no satisfactory discussion of how to resolve it. Clearly, you can just set the `font` of the text field, but I don't see how to specify other attributes, such as the baseline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone in the future who wants to achieve the behavior I was able to do it by subclassing `NSTextView` and essentially faking a `NSTextField` like so:

```
class FakeTextField: NSTextView {

  required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

    delegate = self

    let droidSansMono = NSFont(name: "DroidSansMono", size: 70)!
    configure(lineHeight: frame.size.height, alignment: .center, font: droidSansMono)
  }

  func configure(lineHeight: CGFloat, alignment: NSTextAlignment, font: NSFont) {
    //Other Configuration

    //Define and set typing attributes
    let style = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
    style.minimumLineHeight = lineHeight
    style.maximumLineHeight = lineHeight
    style.alignment = alignment
    style.lineHeightMultiple = 1.0
    typingAttributes = [NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: style, NSFontAttributeName: font]
  }

}

extension TextField: NSTextViewDelegate {
  func textView(_ textView: NSTextView, shouldChangeTextIn affectedCharRange: NSRange, replacementString: String?) -> Bool {
    if let oldText = textView.string, let replacement = replacementString {
      let newText = (oldText as NSString).replacingCharacters(in: affectedCharRange, with: replacement)
      let numberOfChars = newText.characters.count
      let wrongCharacterSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789").inverted
      let containsWrongCharacters = newText.rangeOfCharacter(from: wrongCharacterSet) != nil
      return numberOfChars <= 2 && !containsWrongCharacters
    }
    return false
  }
}
```

With this class, all you need to do is set the `NSTextView` in your storyboard to this class and change the attributes and `shouldChangeTextIn` to suit your needs. In this implementation, the "TextField" has various attributes set and is limited to two characters and only digits.

Comment: @Rob Thank you for the help. I have found what seems to be a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You subclass NSNumberFormatter with the following:

```
final class ChargiePercentageNumberFormatter: NumberFormatter {

    override func attributedString(for obj: Any, withDefaultAttributes attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key : Any]? = nil) -> NSAttributedString? {
        guard let obj = obj as? NSNumber else {
            return nil;
        }
        guard let numberString = self.string(from: obj) else {
            return nil
        }
        let font = NSFont(name: "Poppins-Regular", size: 16)!
        let attrs: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: font, .kern: 1.2]

        let result = NSAttributedString(string: numberString, attributes: attrs)
        return result
    }

}
```